# internet explorer 8 extra div inserted

Tags: html, internet-explorer, layout, internet-explorer-8

I am working on this site: http://gitastudents.com/~clarkb/group1/Students.html

For some reason it does not display properly in ie8.
I think it i just miss-aligned div's but i cannot figure it out.

Ie8 is showing an extra empty div where the java section should be and bumping the java down.

What can i do to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance,
Bryan

Comment: I can't see any "Seniors section". Can you post a more specific link?

Comment: sorry, by I forgot that "seniors" was changed to "java" fixed the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is causing your problem or not (would be easier to troubleshoot if you put it into jsfiddle) but I noticed you don't close the table tag in your Freshman section. Hard to tell what effect it's having. If that doesn't fix your problem, I'd go back through and make sure you've properly formed all your elements.